# Setting Custom Domain in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I set up my A records over the weekend, but I have no idea if I've done it right or not.

[image]

I set up an IP in AWS:

[image]

[image]

But I still can't reach my site:

http://huntingcollective.net/

http://www.huntingcollective.net/

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thoughts?

Comment: No DNS server see that A record https://dnschecker.org/#A/huntingcollective.net, the only records are SOA, NS and MX https://who.is/dns/huntingcollective.net

Comment: So it's not that i did something wrong, it's that I didn't something completely.  I can grok that.  
Of course that leads to my next question, how do I properly set up an A record?

Comment: And it turns out I did do the wrong thing.  Thanks @Martheen

Answer (score 0):

So after guidance from Martheen, I did some more research and I just didn't know what I was doing.
The correct way to set up a DNS record at Namecheap, is to use the @ symbol for your A-record.

[image]